# 12.04 LTS - 14.04 LTS File Manager: No sidebar tree or menu bar

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

After upgrading from Desktop 12.04 LTS to Desktop 14.04 LTS.
The File Manager seems to be severely degraded.
The sidebar no longer allows a tree-structured view of directories.
The menu bar is very limited with no File, Edit, View, etc.
There does not seem to be any alternate means of doing what these things did in 12.04.
Any insights appreciated.
-chaz

Comment: There's supposed to be a gear icon in the top right corner of the Nautilus window, with some options.

Comment: Yes, there is a gear icon.

Comment: Yes, there is a gear icon.  However, it has a very limited list of commands.
There are buttons for large icon view and list view, but no small icon view.
There is a "Down-Arrow" button for options, but although you can choose to display the sidebar, there is no longer a way to change the sidebar so that it displays the directories as a tree.
The entire File Manager (nautilus) interface seems to have been "Dumbed Down" in 14.04.
This seems very odd considering that this is a key interface for the user.
-chaz

Comment: I don't know if the feature even exists now (welcome to GNOME3 as envisioned by the GNOME devs!), but you could try Nemo, which aims to be like old Nautilus while built on GNOME3 libs.

Comment: That's a bit depressing.  Is there any document/statement concerning the direction this is going in?
-chaz

Comment: I dunno. I suppose that would be the [HIG](https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/3.2), but that's more detail than you want, probably. If I say anything more, it'd be flaming GNOME, so I'll hold my peace.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got the answer to this.  Depressing as it is.
The Gnome folks have re-engineered nautilus (Ubuntu File Manager) such that it no longer has these features.  Very strange, but it seems to have been a conscious decision.
There is talk of Ubuntu dropping nautilus as its file manager and replacing it with one derived from merging their phone and tablet file managers.  We'll see...
So it seems like we may have to wait until the next LTS release to get a decent default file manager in Ubuntu.
-chaz

Answer (score 0):

i found this, it works , not the same as before, but you do get a "tree"  kind of navigation, hope it helps you.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120098/how-to-show-the-tree-view-in-left-pane-of-nautilus